# Magento Permanent Customer Session

Tags: session, magento, cookies, authentication

The premise is simple.

New customer arrives at our site, is redirected to the register/login page (since they are a new visitor and no cookie is present) and after registering or logging in (if already have an account but visiting from a different machine/browser) they are taken to the home page.

Every time they subsequently visit, they should not see the register/login page (unless they explicitly log out, cookies are disabled/blocked, or they visit from a different browser/device).

I would think that theoretically, setting the cookie value to an absurdly high number (in our case, 30+ years) and checking for the presence of that cookie before the redirect to the register/login page would work.

In our case it is not. I feel like the session is still lasting roughly an hour or so before a visit back to the home page of the site redirects a user to register/login.

So what am I missing here? Any advice?

---edit---
I had been assured by our web host that session.gc_maxlifetime was not the issue. I set it to 86400 on our development server and after leaving my browser idle overnight, I returned the next day and I think it's working as intended.

One issue I have with this is that it also sets the magento admin timeout to the same value, which may introduce a security risk if an employee is given Magento admin access and then gets fired/quits/etc. I certainly don't want their session to continue for as long as we want customer sessions to last (months).

I'm hoping that the CONFIG>>ADVANCED>>ADMIN>>SECURITY>>SESSION LIFETIME setting is not overridden by this.

Comment: Hi pspahn,how is the issue coming along did you found a solution ?

Comment: I have not had time to get back to this issue for several days. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely with the Php session value you need to increase it to match the value in the cookie duration; on your php.ini put the following:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

You need to replace the '86400' value with what equivalent time that you want the session / cookie to last I would advice that you set your sessions and cookie value'604800' that's about a week.

What is going to happen on your server is that magento is going to a session file per session under the var/sessions folder. This can potentially can cause your server to run out of inodes , depends on your server configuration.

Cheers!

Comment: But will a value of 86400 be adequate to allow a user to maintain an open session if they return in one week? One month? I have a hard time believing this will be good for server performance if we start having thousands of sessions remaining open for that long.

Comment: Also, while fab.com doesn't use Magento (as far as I know), the way they do it is perfect.

Comment: Best thing I can advice is to try it out, depending on your site traffic and server configuration may or may not affect performance.

Comment: This solved ONE of the issues of why it wasn't working. This is making our dev site work as intended, but our production site is still not working after I pushed these changes up. There is an additional problem in the code when dealing with https:// vs. http:// (our dev site does not have SSL).

Comment: pspahn Please describe the problem with the SSL